# Add / Remove to/from favorites change casing to match other items

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

What is wrong with this picture:

[image]

This:

[image]

Please change to lower case to match the rest of the options.  Also change the "Add" to a lower case a when you "add to favorites".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Fixed.

Comment: Ill take it but lower case looked better as we aren't really ending with a . (period) as they aren't sentences..but I'll take it as consistent.